# Is there a way to make the Verilog port declaration based on a macro value?

Tags: verilog, programming, rtl

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is that,
There is a macro REG_COUNT. Based on the value inside the macro, the N number registers get initialized.

But I also want to create dedicated output ports from each of these registers. The number of registers is based on the REG_COUNT macro value, so is there a way to make the output ports also get initialized based on the macro value count?

Similar to how generate works in Verilog, but sadly generate cannot be used for port declarations.

I tried many ways, but I am stuck and cannot seem to get any idea on how to solve this. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
`define REG_COUNT 12'h008 // for a total of 8 registers to be declared.

module md_regbank(
//Since macro value is for 8 registers, I need 8 output ports to be declared here


);

 reg [7:0] register[12'h000:`REG_COUNT];   // 8 registers are there

 always @() begin
 ...............
 end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this.

1. Have an upper limit on the number of registers, and manually declare that many ports. This is rather ugly and limiting, plus distributing signals to said ports is a lot of effort too.

   ```
   module individual_ports (
      output [WIDTH-1:0] individual_0,
      output [WIDTH-1:0] individual_1,
      ... ,
      output [WIDTH-1:0] individual_7
   ); // Max 8 regs`

   wire [WIDTH-1:0] unpacked [N_PORTS-1:0];

   generate
       assign individual_0 = unpacked [0];
       if (N_PORTS > 1) assign individual_1 = unpacked[1];
       if (N_PORTS > 2) assign individual_2 = unpacked[2];
       ...
       if (N_PORTS > 7) assign individual_7 = unpacked[7];
   endgenerate
   ```
2. Simply make the ports wide enough to accommodate all of the registers. Then when connecting them up you use concatenation and part selects.

   ```
   module packed_ports ( 
        output [WIDTH*N_PORTS-1:0] packed
   );
   wire [WIDTH-1:0] unpacked [N_PORTS-1:0];
   // Packing/unpacking the port
   genvar prt;
   generate for (prt = 0; prt < N_PORTS; prt = prt + 1) begin
       assign packed[(prt * WIDTH) +: WIDTH] = unpacked[prt];
   end endgenerate
   ```
3. A newer technique, though perhaps less well supported by synthesis tools, is to use SystemVerilog unpacked array constructs. Here you can declare ports to have a number of different copies.

   ```
   module unpacked_ports (
       output [WIDTH-1:0] unpacked [N_PORTS-1:0]
   ); // Any number and width.

   // No need to unpack, as already unpacked
   ```

---

As an aside, is there a particular reason you are using macros rather than parameters? Parameters can be more easily changed on an instance by instance basis, rather than hard coding a define in the file.

```
module #( parameter REG_COUNT = 12 ) (
   ...
);
reg [7:0] register [12'h000:REG_COUNT];
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solutions. 
The reason I am using macros is because I am trying to make a template code, which can be adapted by anyone. A register bank template, so by specifying the Register_count using macro, the code needs to be pre-complied to match the specific criteria.  
I thought of using the parameter, but then the specifications will be met, but the compiled code size would be large and not efficient for the particular specifications.
Using macro, the precompiled code would be efficient.
This is my thought process. If I am wrong, feel free to suggest corrections.

Comment: @VasantJoseph parametrer vs macro will make zero difference to the resulting netlist output. They are both constants which are optimised away by the synthesis tools. The difference is one can be overridden on an instance by instance basis (parameter), whilst the other can't (well maybe can with some convoluted 'define/'undef use).